# module 'ObjectiveC' in AST file and could not build module

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors

I'm getting several errors when compiling an app on my phone. It works just fine in the simulator, but not for anything else. It started after resetting my device's settings. I've tried creating a new project, but that didn't work. Here are the exact errors.

```
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "dispatch.h"
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:48:2: error: module 'ObjectiveC' in AST file 
 <module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "Headers/CoreFoundation.h"
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:60:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:60:
#include <CoreFoundation/CFPropertyList.h>
     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFPropertyList.h:17:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFPropertyList.h:17:
#include <CoreFoundation/CFStream.h>
     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:20:10: error: could not build module 'Dispatch'
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
     ^
 <unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'CoreFoundation'
```

This doesn't seem to be a code related issue, as this code compiled without any issue the other day. I'm just not sure how to fix it.